# nodejs include required packages in all route files using require() function

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Hi I'm new to nodeJs and currently developing a Rest API using node.I'm planning to develop it with a good folder structure, so I can scale it up easily. There I'm using several route files according to the business logic.

ex :- authRoutes,profileRoutes,orderRoutes ......

Currently in every single route file I had to include following codes

```
var express    = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var passport = require('passport');
```

My problem is , Is it totally fine to use above code segments in all the route files( I'm concerning about the code optimisation/coding standards and execution speed ) or is there any better way to do this.

It's better if you can explain the functionality of require() function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, this is very standard to do. I suggest reading [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34955036/8161432) to learn more about the way it affects the speed of your programs.

**TL;DR of `require()`**

When your lines of code are ran that include a variable that exists because of a `require()`, for instance

```
var https = require('https');
https.get(url, function(response) {...});
```

The compiler reads it and goes into the `https` module folder, and looks for the `.get` function.

However, if you are trying to `require()` a certain JavaScript file, such as `analysis.js`, you must navigate to that file from the file you are *currently* in. For instance, if the file you want is on the same level as the file you are in, you can access it like this:

```
var analysis = require('./analysis.js');
//Let analysis have a function called analyzeWeather
analysis.analyzeWeather(weather_data);
```

These lines of code are a little different from above. In this `require()` statement, we are saying **grab the .js file with this name, analysis**. Once you require it, you can access any public function inside of that `analysis.js` file.

### Edits

- Added `require()` example for `.js` file.